# SQL Count how many outliers within a group by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to count how many elements in every `group by` are greater than $\mu+ \sigma$, $\mu+ 2 \sigma$ and so on.

So far I found a solution creating first a table `gp` with $\mu$ and $\sigma$

```
CREATE TABLE gp AS
SELECT col_a,
       col_b,
       AVG(y) AS y_mean,
       STDDEV(y) AS y_std
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col_a, col_b;
```

Then I do a `left join` with the original table and do the counting via

```
SELECT col_a,
       col_b,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN y>y_mean+y_std THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS std1,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN y>y_mean+2*y_std THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS std2,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN y>y_mean+3*y_std THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS std3, 
FROM (
SELECT a.*,
       b.y_mean,
       b.y_std
FROM(
(SELECT col_a,
       col_b,
       y
FROM my_table) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM gp) b
ON a.col_a=b.col_a AND a.col_b=b.col_b)
)
GROUP BY col_a, col_b
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Mean absolute deviation worked better for me in similar circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT col_a, col_b,
       SUM(CASE WHEN y > y_mean + y_std THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS std1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN y > y_mean + 2 * y_std THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS std2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN y > y_mean + 3 * y_std THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS std3
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             AVG(y) OVER (PARTITION BY col_a, col_b) as y_mean,
             STDDEV(y) OVER (PARTITION BY col_a, col_b) as y_std
      FROM my_table t
     ) t
GROUP BY col_a, col_b;
```

From a statistical perspective, you should be looking at the lower bound as well.  If the distribution is skewed only in the positive direction, then standard deviation might not be the best measure (although you don't have much choice when using databases).

Comment: I'm going to test this later. In this case 'y' are not negative and I need this count in order to have an idea of how many exceptional outliers do I have.

Comment: I could run your query only after removing `t`.